# installing rpm packages on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, rpm

In ubuntu i have downloaded flash rpm,how to install it.i am new to ubuntu and i have tried the following

```
    alien -k flash-plugin-10.0.45.2-release.i386.rpm
    alien -i flash-plugin-10.0.45.2-release.i386.rpm
    rpm -i flash-plugin-10.0.45.2-release.i386.rpm //this works in rhel versions
```

The above doesn't seem to work..

Thanks..

Comment: having run alien it will have output a .deb which you can install with dpkg - but as others have said its not the way to go ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's available [in the repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=flashplugin) and you should use the Synaptic or aptitude package manager to install it rather than downloading and installing it manually.

For Jaunty, Karmic and Lucid:

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

For Dapper, Hardy and Intrepid:

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-nonfree
```

Answer (score 4):

Installing a .rpm on Ubuntu is a last resort and should **not** be used when .deb packages [are available](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/).

Answer (score 1):

RPM files are for RedHat Package Manager, and generally not meant for Ubuntu...

actually the better/preferred way would be to use Repository using #apt-get install

since you have already downloaded RPM and wanna use the same, there are two ways you could follow

[] using 'alien' converting *.rpm RedHat package to a *.deb Debian Package like
*this you alrady performed
*This will convert your RPM to a DEB 
{in your case should be flash-plugin-10.0.45.2-release.i386.deb}
and then you can install deb with:

`#sudo dpkg -i flash-plugin-10.0.45.2-release.i386.deb`

[] other way is converting RPM to CPIO, extracting contents of CPIO and installing from the source

`#rpm2cpio flash-plugin-10.0.45.2-release.i386.rpm | cpio -dimv`

Answer (score 0):

The Flash plugin is also in the [Canonical partner repository](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Adding%20Canonical%20Partner%20Repositories), the package is called *adobe-flashplugin*. Using this you'll automatically get security updates for Flash if they are available